# Is there a way to set the PrimeNG p-fileUpload component to open in a custom folder?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using the PrimeNG p-fileUpload component to upload some files. When I press the select file button, I want the file explorer dialog to open in a custom default folder, for example Desktop, or Videos etc. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, because security reasons.
And How you can be sure that the directory that you want exist in all computers?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it even on file input for regular html, it is forbidden for security reason as clients have different operating systems for instance desktop directory in windows doesn't exist in Mac Os